# Updating registry remotely in powershell not saving after reboot

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, registry, powershell-remoting

I am doing an automated deployment process within a single server that deploys a few different virtual machines. Once all the virtual machines are imported using a base image I start them and rename them and try to setup the auto logon process by setting the expected registry keys.

```
    Remove-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" -Name "AutoLogonCount" -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" -Name "DefaultUserName" -Value "$Username" -Force
    Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" -Name "DefaultPassword" -Value "$Password" -Force
    Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" -Name "AutoAdminLogon" -Value "1" -Force
```

This is wrapped in an Invoke-Command with a working session and passing in the correct information into it. After this has been ran I use `[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey(` method to obtain the key value information and verify it has been set correctly. Which everything equals what it should.

However once this is complete I do a reboot of the virtual machine but occasionally a vm will not have the registry keys saved and it will not login automatically. When I manually login and look at the registry the keys are blank or not created.

I even have it written up that after the reboot if the registry keys do not equal what they should to try again, and after every attempted reboot to login automatically the keys seemingly disappear. I am running it again as I am writing this to attempt to do it and this time look in the event logs to see if anything is found.

This process can take some time since it doesn't seem to happen consistently and I delete the vms and run the automated process from scratch.

Comment: Look to using DSC in your deployment effort.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dsc/getting-started/winGettingStarted   ---   https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/want-to-automatically-configure-your-machines-using-dsc-at-initial-boot-up/

Comment: I have not heard of that, however this system has a lot too it and would be a lot to move everything into DSC. I will definitely look into that for future automation, however would still like to figure out why the registry is not saving.